# How do I use Flaticon icon fonts in NativeScript?

Tags: telerik, icons, nativescript, nativescript-plugin

I have a Vanilla JavaScript NativeScript app, I'd like to use icon fonts from [Flaticon](https://www.flaticon.com/), as described [here](https://www.flaticon.com/iconfonts), 
I did paste the .ttf font file, and add 'class="flaticon-airplane"' to , and I also tried giving an id to the label and apply 'font-family: "Flaticon"' style to the id, but still, did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use class name by default, you can only use the character code. If you are interested in using class names, you should also copy the CSS file and register the CSS path with [nativescript-fonticon](https://github.com/NathanWalker/nativescript-fonticon) plugin.

```
import * as application from 'application';
import {TNSFontIcon, fonticon} from 'nativescript-fonticon';

TNSFontIcon.paths = {
  'flaticon': 'your-flaticon-stylesheet.css'
};
TNSFontIcon.loadCss();
application.setResources( { fonticon } );
```

Comment: What is character code? Where are character codes of icons of the flaticon icon font? Where and how I use those character codes? What should I do if I couldn't reference of character code of the icons?

Comment: You can find the character code in the CSS file that comes with the font. Just take a look at the ReadMe of the plugin linked above, it has answers for all your questions.

Comment: I want to use the hex or character codes of Flaticon icons font, how can I find them while Flaticon has not provided a reference to those character codes, it only listed the class name to the icons. 
Or how I convert the icon class name to character code...?

Comment: Where do you find the CSS file - that's the question for your vendor, every font icon FontAwesome / Ionic / MaterialIcons etc., comes with a CSS file that is the one translates the class names into actual font codes. Since the website requires registration before downloading the pack, I couldn't check it myself.

Comment: Yes, Flaticon.css file is provided

Comment: Flaticon it does not require registration at all,
Just select some icons (it goes to your collection box automatically), and download the collection as icon font...

Comment: I FOUND IT! You were right, there is in fact character code for the icons. Thank you so much!